# I can connect to my remote database via command line but not from golang, although local db works fine with both

Tags: mysql, database, go

If I run the following from command prompt...

```
mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u myuser -p mydb
```

I can access the database and successfully run a query from the sql> command prompt

However, when I use the `database/sql` package in Golang get the following...

> [0/0]0x0Error 1045: Access denied for user
>   'myuser'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)

Please see code below...

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", myuser:mypassword@tcp(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306)/mydb)

if err != nil {
    color.Red(err.Error())
}
var objects []map[string]interface{}

rows, err := db.Query("select * from mytable" , args...)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Please note the `db` var seems fine as if it connects to the database, it's when i try to populate the rows var i get the error.

Also i created unit tests which create a database and table and test a query these all work fine.

Al firewalls etc are off.

so to summarise...

> Remote + Command Prompt -  works
>
> local + golang - is fine
>
> Remote + golang  - gets the error

Comment: Your go code is invalid, and won't compile. Please copy and paste your code directly (then edit out the password).

Comment: @Anshu: More likely, the user isn't granted remote access in mysql.

Comment: @flimzy..but the given error.the user don't have authentication to access the database.

Comment: i can connect remotely from command prompt

Comment: "i can connect remotly from command prompt" -- Then it must be a bad username or password, or you're connecting over a different network type with different security settings (such as IPv4 vs IPv6)

Comment: @Anshu: I'm pretty sure the error message is the same in both cases.

Comment: Ok @Flimzy sure you're right.... Thanks 

Comment: Ok part of the unit test was throwing it off as the user only has select rights, it could not create the database so it did not even get the the select query